# How to disable Ctrl+F4?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working with MDIs, and I have an MDI parent and childs. But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> it closes the MDI child.

I am currently working on KeyEvents to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
    Select Case (keyData)
        Case Keys.Control Or Keys.F4
            Return True
        Case Keys.Control
            Return True
    End Select
    Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)
End Function
```

I can't get this working for me... How can I fix it?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong method, it isn't a dialog.  And be sure you put it in the MDI parent form, not the child.  This works:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.F4) Then Return True
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```